# How to print messages from running jar file?

Tags: java

Lately I've been working on building two tools using Eclipse. I'm printing some messages to the console there (`System.out.print`).
However, I've now constructed a .jar file for each tool, which I want to run on a different machine (no eclipse installed). Running this .jar does not provide me with the messages I'm printing.

What is the best way to print messages to the screen from a running .jar file?
For example, how to print:

```
System.out.print("Results succesfully saved!");
```

I've googled quite a bit, but couldn't find any results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`System.out.print("Results succesfully saved!");` will work just as fine for a .jar-program. However, it requires the user to run it in a terminal so that he sees the stuff printed to standard output.

If this is not what you're after, then perhaps you want to have a look at [`JOptionPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) which has a few static methods to graphically display messages like those.

This screenshot

[image]

is for instance produced by this snippet:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Results succesfully saved!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the JOptionPane looks nice.

However, strange thing is that I did try to run it from the command line (Windows 7) and it didn't print any of my print statements to the command line.

Comment: exactly how did you run it? can't o even see the output of a simple hello world program? that sounds extremely strange...

Comment: Ah, I found out what I did wrong in console.. Instead of running `java -jar xx.jar` I ran `xx.jar`. Running with `java -jar` I get the expected print output indeed. The swing alternative looks nice as well, so I'm still considering changing to JOptionPanes. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Are you execute jars from console? If not than try it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this works for Linux, but for windows you have to go into your control panel, open the java settings, go to advanced. And select Java console -> show console.

Of course even better is to use a log framework, such as [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/),  instead of System.out.println. That way you can print both to file and to console.

Answer (score 0):

Printing to the screen will word just as fine when you execute your program "more directly". However you might want to consider using a logging framework since it offers you more flexibility when you want to configure your output.