# Making a Debugging Console

Tags: java, debugging, console

I couldn't find any information when I was searching for this (Maybe I was searching the wrong keywords) but I need a way I can have a debugger during runtime outputting my own strings of words, kind of like System.out.print statements but to a console window instead.

Maybe I am just a noob but I want to ask this too before someone tells me this: Does the system.out.print, println, and printf statements print to a command prompt during runtime after you finish your program and create a jar. My program uses JFrame with severeal GUIs.

Comment: Maybe check out this question here?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078351/how-to-print-messages-from-running-jar-file

Comment: Yes thank you that is good enough for what I wanted, if you have ever loaded minecraft feed the beast server, the console that is in the background is what I am after, but this will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a new frame with a JTextArea covering it, everytime I have a System.out.println() I just used a static addToDebugger(String s) method which just concatenates JTextArea.getText() with a "\n" + s and then JTextArea.setText().